# Can not see the value of @Input in console but available in HTML

Tags: angular

In my Angular 4 project I am passing a value form parent component which is coming by a service call. The child component is receiving that value and also available in my HTML. But when I am consoling that passed value in my child component typescript file it is showing undefined.

Here are my code snippets step by step:-

restaurantlayout.component.ts (Parent Component ts file):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RestaurantService } from '../../services/restaurant.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurantlayout',
  templateUrl: './restaurantlayout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurantlayout.component.css'],
  providers: [RestaurantService]
})

export class RestaurantlayoutComponent implements OnInit {

    public menuarray;
    public bannerarray;
    public popularArray; //passing data
    constructor(private restaurantservice:RestaurantService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.restaurantservice.getPartcularRestaurantDetailsByidOrSlug()
            .subscribe((data:Response)=>{
                this.menuarray = data.json().menu['menu'] ;
                this.bannerarray = data.json().basicDetails['basicDetails'];
                this.popularArray = data.json().popular['popular'];
            }
        );
    }

}
```

restaurantlayout.component.html (Parent Alyout Html file)

```
    <section class="restaurant-details-main">
    <app-restaurantbanner [bannerSection]="bannerarray"></app-restaurantbanner>

</section>
<section class="restaurant-mid-body">
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="row">
            <app-restaurantmenu [menuSection]="menuarray"></app-restaurantmenu>
            <app-restaurantrecomend [popularSection]="popularArray">

            </app-restaurantrecomend> <!-- passed here  -->
            <app-restaurantbasket>

            </app-restaurantbasket>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The child component typescript file code:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurantrecomend',
  templateUrl: './restaurantrecomend.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurantrecomend.component.css']
})
export class RestaurantrecomendComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() popularSection:string[];

    public decrementDisabled = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.popularSection); //giving undefined but available 
                                      //in HTML file
```

}

```
  increment(popular){
    this.decrementDisabled = false;
    popular.count++;
  }

  decrement(popular){
    popular.count--;
  }

  addTobasket(popularitem){
    popularitem.cost = (popularitem.count*popularitem.item_price);
    this.data.changeBasketState(popularitem);
  }

}
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020950/angular-in-which-lifecycle-hook-is-input-data-available-to-the-component). It looks like the asynchronous service that is populating the `@Input` field is causing this.

Comment: Value for the input property is set from the parent in an asynchronous operation...

Answer (score 4):

Your parent component retrieves `popularArray` with an asynchronous operation, which is then passed to the child as `popularSection`. This means that when the child component runs its `ngOnInit` method, the service call hasn't finished yet, and `popularSection` is still undefined.

Change your `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges` and you'll see that the variable is first undefined, and as soon as the service returns it, the child will log the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Value for the input property is set from the parent in an asynchronous operation.

You could use a setter in the child component to get the value in ts file.
Setter for input gets executed whenever change is detected in the input property.